# Trying to make 3 x 3 montage of 9 images using ImageMagick but getting error for command line command

Tags: image, image-processing, image-editing, montage, imagemagick-montage

I am trying to make a large montage of 9 images in a grid of 3x3 on my windows 10 laptop. Image size of all 9 images are same. I did a research on Internet and found how to do it either vertically or horizontally but not for a array of images or grid. I downloaded [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) software from their website to use their command line options as shown in [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) but when I use the command given below, I get error `montage is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Please help or suggest another way to do it. Thanks

Here is the command I am using
`montage 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg 5.jpg 6.jpg 7.jpg 8.jpg 9.jpg -geometry +3+3+3 montage_geom.jpg`

Comment: Note that if you use `bash`, you can specify all those files as `[1-9].jpg` or if the numbers are not contiguous or you want them in a different order `{3,2,1,55,56,57,8,9,10}.jpg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your montage ImageMagick syntax is incorrect.  Try

```
magick montage 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg 5.jpg 6.jpg 7.jpg 8.jpg 9.jpg -geometry +3+3 -tile 3x3 montage_geom.jpg
```

```
-tile specifies the 3 rows and 3 columns structure
-geometry specifies the horizontal and vertical spacing between images
```

If using the older v6 **ImageMagick**, omit the `magick` at the start of the command.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit, roll it back if you do. I think OP has downloaded v7 IM, maybe on Windows without checking the *"Legacy Commands"* box.

Comment: Mark, good point about his possibly using IM 7.  Your changes are fine.

Comment: Thank you Mark and fmw42 for your help. I am using 7.0.10-27 Q16 x64 2020-08-10 version on Windows 10